# Is editing job descriptions broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I'm trying to update my jobs descriptions as I updated my resume, but when I try to edit, even though I change the text in the Responsibilities field, it doesn't update when I click Save. In fact the form for editing stays open and nothing happens. If I refresh the page, the old description appears. But if I click Edit again, the new text is shown. I've tried forcing a refresh (<kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>) and the problem doesn't go away. What is going on?

Comment: I guess it's a bug indeed. I have myself reproduced the problem and I can also see other peers with the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was indeed a bug, introduced by what was thought to be only a styling change.  It's fixed now. Thank you for reporting it.

For those interested, as part of the styling change, a `<input name='save' type='button'...` was changed to `<button name='save'...`.  The `input` will actually submit a form param named `save` with the value of the button, while the `button` does not submit the form param.  Thus, the backend didn't realize "save" was getting clicked.

Comment: Yey! Fun stuff... It's working now! I'll try to not make the same mistake in my projects. Thanks! 