# Create new roles on developers history doesn't take effect

Tags: bug, developer-story

I'm creating the entry on user story but when click on the save button nothing happens.
The network `/submit` respond 200 but refreshing the page the entry disappears.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is the same problem: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398196/is-editing-job-descriptions-broken