# Developer story won't let me add past Positions

Tags: support, bug, developer-story

I want to create a resume on Stack Overflow with past positions. But if I try to add a past position, the UI just gives me the possibility to add one position (my current position) to my developer story. It just won't add it. What is going on here?

This is issue is probably related to this one:
*[Is editing job descriptions broken?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398196/is-editing-job-descriptions-broken)*

And this one: *[Create new roles on developers history doesn't take effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398249/create-new-roles-on-developers-history-doesnt-take-effect)*